# Mayavi saving pics issues

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, mayavi

I'm developing a desktop app which uses the Mayavi package. So, I'm using `anaconda` with `mayavi 4.4.0` and `pyqt 4.11.3` (`python 2.7`). When I try to save the image using the Mayavi interface I get:

```
KGlobal::locale(): Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
kfilemodule(5709): couldn't create slave: "Unable to create io-slave:
klauncher said: Unknown protocol ''.
" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/facu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/ui/qt4/action/action_item.py", line 358, in _qt4_on_triggered
    action.perform(action_event)
  File "/home/facu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/action/action.py", line 100, in perform
    self.on_perform()
  File "/home/facu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tvtk/pyface/ui/qt4/decorated_scene.py", line 159, in _save_snapshot
    if dialog.open() == OK:
  File "/home/facu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/i_dialog.py", line 122, in open
    self.close()
  File "/home/facu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/ui/qt4/file_dialog.py", line 103, in close
    self.wildcard_index = self.control.nameFilters().index(
AttributeError: 'QStringList' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I have fixed others issues editing `*.py` files, I don't know how to fix this one in particular .

Comment: Are you using a standalone mayavi window or is this part of a GUI ? If you are using a GUI can you provide a minimal working example with the relevant features of your GUI which, when you save (or run `mlab.savefig`) reproduces your error?

Comment: It is a standalone mayavi window.